# FIFA19 - overall rating is higher for specific country?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, means, anova

Hy, I was studying this data set on Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/karangadiya/fifa19) for my machine learning problem. Idea is to from features of player to count overall rating.
Ok, first we need a little bit of feature engineering to see what feature will be significant.
One of this is country of player such as Croatia or Brasil.

Main idea is that country of player wouldn't have much impact on overall rating, but what if developer with intention give Brasil player much higher rating than Croatia player.The same idea can be used in club(Maybe equal player in Real Madrid and Dinamo Zagreb have higher rating if he play in RM).

So the problem is to show that country of player has no connection to overall.
To try to solve this problem I use all Croatia and Brasil player and use T-test on their overall rating. The test show that Brasil player have higher rating, but this can be also reason that Brasil have better players.
Another idea was also use T-test again but overall / value for Croatia and Brasil but I didn't get any clear answer.

Can you give idea how to approach the problem?

Comment: There is not a simple answer to the question.  One issue to consider is that the best players in Brazil may be better than the best players in Croatia partly because the population of Brazil is larger.  If so, would this mean that being Brazilian affects skill, or that there is selection bias?

Comment: One check to do is to check if the average overall rating of a country is correlated to the FIFA world rankings... or the sales of the product in different nations!

Comment: This should be posted on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). I am removing the bounty and closing the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ but it needs improvement before posting there.